# I can't select the item in the ExtJs grid

Tags: extjs, grid

everyone.

I'm using ExtJs to create a grid with more than 100 records, and I can't select/highlight one of them within the grid.
It always select/highlight the first record when I tried to click another one.
But when I added the new records, these items can be selected/highlighted.

Anyone know the possible reason?

Comment: can you post some code?

Comment: @YetAnotherProgrammer Just get the store from web service, and bind it to the grid component